# How do explicitly create temporary by pointer?

Tags: c++, initialization

```
int i=int();    //OK  
int* pi=int*(); //error
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you elaborate?

Comment: he's trying to construct a pointer to an int :) see my answer

Comment: `typedef int* ptr; ptr pi = ptr()` works, but I don't know how to do it without a `typedef`.

Comment: @Mzn: what I don't understand is the "temporary" part in the question title.

Comment: That is kind of ambiguous, but I guessed he meant local scope; in local scope, variables and pointers to them are "temporary"

thanks for the edit! I was struggling to get the formatting right :)

Comment: To expand on @anatolyg 's comment, the standard requires certain operations to work with type aliases.  For example, in a templated function `T a; a.~T()` must compile, invoking a destructor even if `T` is `int` (barring someone explicitly deleting their destructor or something similar).  However, `int a; a~int()` doesn't compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can default initialize both of them with uniform initialization.

```
int i{};
int *ip{};
```

The constructor like calls are unnecessary and convoluted, as of course, behave differently for some types as you've found out yourself.

If what you're trying to do is have the pointer point to space allocated for an int, you'll need to allocate with `new`

```
int *ip = new int;
```

or give it the address of an existing int

```
int i{};
int *ip = &i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't construct a pointer. You get it by:

1. Getting a reference:

   ```
   int x;
   int* xpointer = &x; //pointer to x
   ```
2. Creating using `new`:

   ```
    int* x = new int;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int * i = new int();
```

This is basic C++, maybe you need to familiarize yourself with dynamic memory allocation. This is a good enough resource on the subject: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/